# JAXB XML to object serializing

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb

I have this XML structure:

```
<diagnosedSystemTypes>
   <string>system_1</string>   
   <string>system_2</string>
   <string>system_3</string>
   <string>system_4</string>
</diagnosedSystemTypes>
```

What im trying to do is, to deserialize this  elements to DiagnosedSystemTypes list.

This is how looks my DiagnosedSystemType class.

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "string" )
public class DiagnosedSystemType {

    String name; 

    @XmlElement (name = "string")
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

While this diagnosedSystemTypes are nested in Server tag, i put this fields in Server class.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "diagnosedSystemTypes")
@XmlElement (name = "string")
List<DiagnosedSystemType> diagnosedSystemTypes = null;
```

Now during the deserialization, i got proper list of diagnosedSystemTypes, but the string element inside, are null's :( It's strange, because the number of elements inside the list are ok (4). Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "diagnosedSystemTypes" )
public class DiagnosedSystemType {

    @XmlElement (name = "string")
    List<String> names; 


    public List<String> getNames(){
        if (names == null) names = new ArrayList<>();
        return name;
    }
}
```

Your diagnosedSystemTypes contains list of Strings not just one name.